# Angular - changing ngModel value manually doesn't detect the value as valid

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I'm changing the value of a select in my template:

```
        <select id="CollaboratorId" 
                    name="CollaboratorId"
                    formControlName="CollaboratorId"
                    class="form-control col-sm-8" 
                    [(ngModel)]="SelectedUser.CollaboratorId" 
                    (change)="onUserChange($event.target.value)" required>
                <option [ngValue]="undefined">Select Collaborator</option>
                <option *ngFor="let collaborator of CollaboratorsList" [ngValue]="collaborator.collaboratorId">{{collaborator.collaboratorFullName}}</option>
        </select>
```

From my component with its ngModel name like this:

```
this.SelectedUser.CollaboratorId = data.collaboratorId;
```

When running my program I can see indeed the value has changed, however because the value wasn't selected on change it's not being registered as valid. I know there's no way to change a form's control to valid, so is there a method to instead trigger the (change)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not working properly because you are mixing reactive and template driven forms. Try removing [(ngModel)].